# simple superscript and subscript syntax parser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

when users enter a string (this is also what is saved in the database):

m/s^[2]

the javascript should display this as meters per second squared - the 2 in superscript.  And same for subscript:

x_[1]

so I think I need a regex and javascript function to detect the syntax and replace with subscript and superscript syntax.

```
function myFunction($formula) {
    //check $formula for sub/sup syntax enclosed with _[..]  and ^[..]
    //replace with javascript sup() and sub() 
    //return string
}
```

It's just for sub and superscripting (nothing else).

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uJ4jX5/2)

`(?:.*\^\[(\d+)\]|.*_\[(\d+)\])`

You'll have to test the matches.

If the first group is not empty, replace with sup 
If the second group is not empty then replace with sub.